# Write down basis for the set of all polynomials $f(x)$ of degree at most 5 such that $f(2) = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Write down basis for the set of all polynomials $f(x)$ of degree at most 5 such that $f(2) = 0$.

I know there are lots of answers you could write, but would this be correct:

$\{(x-2)^5, (x-2)^4, (x-2)^3, (x-2)^2, (x-2)^1\}$?

or

$\{(x-2)^5, (x-2)^4, (x-2)^3, (x-2)^2, (x-2)^1, 1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

The set of polynomials $f(x)$ of degree at most 5, is a six-dimensional set because they have six coefficients.  The restriction $f(2)=0$ is a linear relation between them, so you have a subspace of dimension 5.  You need five basis vectors.
Also, the constant polynomial $f(x)=1$ does not satisfy $f(2)=0$.

Comment: Would $B= \{(x-2)^5, (x-2)^4, (x-2)^3, (x-2)^2, (x-1)^1, -1\}$ work? What would the dimension of $B$ be? What would the dimension of $S = $ set of all polynomials $f(2)=0$?

Comment: Your first example in the question works.  $B$ does not work, for both reasons I gave in my answer.

Comment: Why doesn't $B$ work? If you put x=2, you get 0.

Comment: If $B$ is a basis, then every linear combination of the set has $f(2)=0$.  But $f(x)=1(x-2)^5+1(x-2)^4+0(x-2)^3+0(x-2)^2+0(x-1)^1+1(-1)$ has $f(2)=0+0+0+0+0-1$, so that linear combination is not in the set.